# Angular; How to send Image to back-end api by http get method

Tags: javascript, angular, http, http-get

I have this method to send image base64 data to back-end api to return images similar to this image:

```
getProducts(term = 'filter=', brands: string[] = [], categories: string[]= [], fileTypes: string[]= [], imageUploaded = '',
            pageNumber = 0, pageSize = 3): Observable<PaginatedResult<Product[]>> {
   const paginatedResult: PaginatedResult<Product[]> = new PaginatedResult<Product[]>();
   let params = new HttpParams();
   params = params.append('pageNumber', (pageNumber - 1).toString());
   params = params.append('pageSize', pageSize.toString());
   return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.baseUrl
    + 'publicproducts/GetPublicProducts/' + term + '/' + brands.join('_') + '/' +
     categories.join('_') + '/' + fileTypes.join('_'),
     { observe: 'response', params})
  .pipe(
    map(response => {
      paginatedResult.result = response.body;
      if (response.headers.get('Pagination') != null) {
        paginatedResult.pagination = JSON.parse(response.headers.get('Pagination'));
      }
      return paginatedResult;
    }));
}
```

I need to know how can I put base64 to my http get method.

Comment: You can try this:https://therichpost.com/how-to-upload-image-with-laravel-angular/

Comment: this sample uses http POST method but I need http GET

Comment: Let me share wait

Comment: here is that : https://therichpost.com/angular-8-with-laravel-6-backend-working-example/

Comment: I need to put the imageUploaded  variable in the query not in the response!

Comment: How is your backend? What parameters take .Can u put you get method in api ? Then If u use get method u may also have problem url limit. You have to up the limit too.

Comment: I need to put imageUploaded parameter of this method in the body of the get method, but the get method does not have body parameter